# synchronizing pouchDB with json data

Tags: json, web-services, pouchdb

I want to create a html page which synchronize JSON data with pouch Db.
The JSON data is a response from a web service.I have created a sample html file which can create a pouch Db database.I have created rest web service which gives certain data as response. can any one help me to synchronize these two.

Comment: can any one refer me a tutorial...

Comment: Take a look at this blog post: http://calvinmetcalf.com/post/39926807885/pouchdb-an-intro. It goes through making an app with PouchDB. It has 4 parts to it.

Comment: @benr thanks for the reply...i read the document.. im new in this field....i would appreciate if you could help me more...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PouchDB has a [built in method](http://pouchdb.com/api.html#replication) for synchronizing with [CouchDB](http://couchdb.apache.org) using one- or two-way replication.

I understand that you want to sync with a datasource, which doesn't have a CouchDB compatible API. Then you'll have to write code to perform the synchronization with your specific JSON API.

Answer (score 2):

There's a library now which makes it possible to import a JSON string (dump) as database into PouchDB.

It's called [PouchDB-Load](https://github.com/nolanlawson/pouchdb-load) and is written by PouchDB author Nolan Lawson.

So in your case the code can be as simple as:

`var db = new PouchDB('my-awesome-db');
db.load('http://example.com/my-dump-file.json').then(function () {
  // done loading!
}).catch(function (err) {
  // HTTP error or something like that
});`